# Shout option payoff replication

Tags: option-pricing, european-options, exotics, replication, payoff

I have not seen much talk about exotic options, and if they are actually traded. Is it possible to replicate the payoff of a ‘Shout option’ using standard European/American call and put options?

Comment: If I Google "shout option", the second entry after Wikipedia (HKUST) explains how it can be replicated. Exotic options are traded heavily although shout options are extremely uncommon in Europe and North America in my experience.